# Return Calculations Incorrect in Panel Data

Tags: stata, panel-data

I'm currently working with panel data in Stata, and run the following commands to define the panel:

```
encode ticker, generate(ticker_n)
xtset ticker_n time
```

Where the ticker is a string (ticker of a listed company on a stock exchange), and time is an integer going from 930 (opening of the market) to 1559 (closing of the market). Thus, time here indicates the minutes the stock exchange is opened. For each minute the stock market is opened we have all close prices of the tickers listed at the stock exchange. A sample of the data looks as such:

```
date        time    open    high    low     close   volume  ticker  ticker_n
09/15/2008  930     33.31   33.31   33.31   33.31   2135    zeus    zeus
09/15/2008  931     32.94   32.94   32.94   32.94   100     zeus    zeus
09/15/2008  930     10.21   10.21   10.21   10.21   4270    bx      bx
09/15/2008  931     10.46   10.5    10.42   10.44   5700    bx      bx
```

Then, in an attempt to calculate returns (using the close price) I run the following command:

```
gen return = (close - l.close) / l.close
```

However, this leads to a weird error where every whole hour (time = 1100, 1200, 1300, etc.) the returns are not calculated at all and Stata just reports a "-" for the returns.

Now I assume something went wrong in defining the panel data, such that Stata does not recognize that the observation before 1500 should be 1459 (it looks for 1499 I assume?).

Hence, my question is, how do I correctly define my panel data such that Stata recognizes that my time axis is in minutes? I did not find anything in the official Stata documentation that helped me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed: your `time` variable is messing you up mightily. If `time` is going from 1059 to 1100, or from 1159 to 1200, each of those is a jump of 41 to Stata. The value for the time previous to 1100 would have been at time 1099, which won't be in your data; hence previous values for 1100, etc., will all be missing. There is no sense whatsoever in which Stata will look at 1100 and say "Oh! that's a time and so the previous time would have been 1059 and I should use the value for 1059". Applying a time display format wouldn't change that failure to see the times as you understand them.

You don't explain how daily dates are supposed to enter your analysis. Here is some technique for times in hours and minutes alone.

```
clear 
input time 
930
931 
959 
1000
1001 
1059
1100  
end 

gen double mytime = dhms(0, floor(time/100), mod(time, 100), 0) 

format mytime %tcHH:MM

gen id = 1 
xtset id mytime, delta(60000)  

list mytime L.mytime, sep(0)  

     +-----------------+
     |               L.|
     | mytime   mytime |
     |-----------------|
  1. |  09:30        . |
  2. |  09:31    09:30 |
  3. |  09:59        . |
  4. |  10:00    09:59 |
  5. |  10:01    10:00 |
  6. |  10:59        . |
  7. |  11:00    10:59 |
     +-----------------+
```